# Live stream backup/alternative source

Tags: linux, backup, ffmpeg, ffserver

Hello I Am using ffmpeg and ffserver to stream mpegts with h264 encoding on an Ubuntu Server

How Can I create a backup/alternative server so that if server1 stopped for any reason server2 takes its place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most services don't have such a feature build in because failover should be managed by the server itself, not by each individual service. The services [Heartbeat](http://www.linux-ha.org/) and [Pacemaker](http://clusterlabs.org/) are a pretty good solution and available for every mainstream distribution.

If you need help configuring it, just Google; there are a lot of usefull resources besides the two links I provided above, such as [this](http://opentodo.net/2012/04/configuring-a-failover-cluster-with-heartbeat-pacemaker) one.

**Warning**: Failover clustering *will* add complexity and thus more headaches to your life...